# Range Primes C++

Tags: c++, range, primes

I have a question, I have this assignment
Given a positive integer X, we want to find the shortest interval [A,B] with X contained within it,Where also, A and B are primes numbers.

**Input**
The first line of input contains an integer M (1 <= M <= 100). M lines follow, each with a number X
(1 < X <= 10^5).

**Output**
M lines containing A and B (1 < A <= B <= 10^6), B-A <= 10^4.

**Sample Input**

2

2

4

**Sample Output**

2 2

3 5

I did this, but this doesn't solve the problem. How can I print the primes of the X number? if I don't have a range.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, c = 0, c2 = 0, res = 0, nc = 0;
    cout << "Introduce el limite de numeros: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
        for (c2 = 1; c2 <= n; c2++) {
            res = c % c2;
            if (res == 0) {
                nc = nc + 1;
            }
        }
        if (nc == 2) {
            cout << " " << c;
        }
        nc = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You stated that you "have a question". However, a careful examination shows a complete absence of an actual question. The only thing your post contains is a status update for your homework assignment. That's not a specific question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Said exactly the right thing, but may as well add the MCVE link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: IIRC There are about 6500 prime numbers between [0, 65536] and you can google for a full list. For a problem of that size, any search algorithm is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the formula for find which numbers are the primes, and then compare with your X number, then sum 1 or rest 1.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is for an Online Judge (as it seems to be) then you should try with something like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define MAX 1000005
#define endl '\n'

using namespace std;

bool prime[MAX];
vector<int> primes;

void build() {
    memset(prime, true, sizeof prime);
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;

    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (!prime[i]) continue;
        primes.push_back(i);

        for (int j = i + i; j < MAX; j += i) {
            prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    build();

    int m;
    cin >> m;

    while (m--) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;

        auto b = lower_bound(primes.begin(), primes.end(), x);
        auto a = b;

        if (*a != primes[0])
            a--;

        cout << *a << " " << *b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It just builds an Eratosthenes Sieve and then performs binary search looking for the lowest prime that is >= to the given number and then looks (if it isn't the smallest) for its predecessor. `x` will be contained in that interval; and of course is easy to note that it's the smallest possible interval.

Comment: It's homework for an algorithm class. It Kind of give me an a better idea that I had. Thanks

Comment: [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) tells you that there is always a prime number between n and 2n.  That gives you an upper limit for the size of sieve you have to build: sqrt(2 * 10^5).